# Anime about a boy and a girl trying to keep three robots safe from capture

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm searching for an old anime, I think it was the '90s when I saw it but it's probably from the '80s. There were two kids helping either two or three robots (about their size if I recall). The general plot seemed to be trying to keep them from some organization or the military trying to capture the robots. The robots might have been colored blue, pink, and green. The last scene I remember from the anime involved them being surrounded by the organization/military.

I remember watching it on VHS and it's been bugging me lately trying to remember what show this was. Since it was a rental I don't have a copy in the house anywhere to search through. It seemed to be, what was then, a modern day rather than being super futuristic. Definitely not *Transformers* and pretty sure it's not the colored robots from the *He-Man* series that popped up.

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is [*Saber Marionette*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saber_Marionette). Not a movie, but a series.

They have 3 parts: Saber Marionette J, Saber Marionette J again, and Saber Marionette J to X.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain how this anime matches the description provided by the OP in their question. It'd help other users determine how likely this answer is to be correct or not.

Comment: Kind of lost track of the post/site. It's not Saber Marionette j unfortunatellu.
 Still trying to figure out what cartoon it was but it was about three robots (if i'm remembering right.)  being helped by kids to avoid being captured by the military if I'm remembering right.  They looked more like robots than marionettes or people. 

I do appreciate the attempted help though.